# Match everything between 2 identifiers

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the phrase between identifier `\` if the word `NULL` is present within.

Regex attempt:

```
/\\(.*?)\\/g
```

String:

```
id,name,age,score\n1,Jack,NULL,12\n17,Betty,28,11\cvdvdfv\dfsdfsdf
```

so far all the text between identifiers '' are selected if I try to fit the NULL word it doesn't do anything
Regex attempt:

```
/\\(NULL)(.*?)\\/g
```

I would really appreciate any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/\\[^\\]*NULL[^\\]*\\/g
```

If you actually want to find a whole line between LF, newlines, with a string `NULL`, replace `\\` with `\n` and `[^\\]` with `[^\n]`:

```
/\n.*NULL.*\n/g
```

Or, perhaps, you would just use `/.*NULL.*/g`.

**Details**

- `\\` - a backslash
- `[^\\]*` - 0 or more chars other than a backslash
- `NULL` - `NULL` string
- `[^\\]*` - 0 or more chars other than a backslash
- `\\` - a backslash.

In this concrete case, you may use:

```js
function solution(S) {
    return S.split('\n').filter(x => !/\bNULL\b/.test(x)).join('\n');
}
undefined
console.log(solution('header,header\nANNUL,ANNULLED\nnull,NILL\nNULL,NULL'))
```

Comment: works perfectly. can I ask you another scenario, if that's ok? how do I identify the phrase where NULL is present if the phrase is at the end `header,header\nANNUL,ANNULLED\nnull,NILL\nNULL,NULL`

Comment: @AdeN Then use an alternation, `/\\[^\\]*NULL[^\\]*(?:\\|$)/g`,  `/\n.*NULL.*(?:\n|$)/g` or just - as I said - `/.*NULL.*/g`.

Comment: close, but not quite, I have run it and it captures the mid-phrase https://regexr.com/

Comment: @AdeN regexr is not to trust, show the real code example, use jsfiddle.net for JavaScript, or ideone.com for a lot of languages.

Comment: ohh no, sorry for being pushy. What would you suggest to do? How do I clear a row that contains NULL without using REGEX https://jsbin.com/pigepeliva/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @AdeN `function solution(S) {
    return S.split('\n').filter(x => !x.includes('NULL')).join('\n');
}`, or `function solution(S) {
    return S.split('\n').filter(x => !/\bNULL\b/.test(x)).join('\n');
}`